# Cannot get display of main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have code like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main);
boolean autoLogin = false;
autoLogin = checkAutoLogin();
if(autoLogin) {
    showProgress();// Show progress dialog
    if(login(savedUserName,savedPassword)) {
        //call  home activity using startActivity();
    }
    //  login(savedUserName,savedPassword), this function access the server and return true if username and password correct- this works properly 
}
```

}

Now the question is, i get display of `home activity` without displaying `main activity` and its `progress dialog`, during the authentication time of `login(savedUserName,savedPassword)`(this function take countable time because of server authentication) function, I got only a black screen, during this time i want show main activity and progress dialog.
 
Note:If i click back button in `home activity` i can get `main activity` and `progress dialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do the network operation on UI thread,you can do it in separate thread and then you can call the home activity using Handler object,it iwll solve your problem

Comment: As long as the thread is created and started from the activity, it lives and dies with the UI thread. That is rarely desirable. Do the work in a background thread, but create and start it from a Service

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your `showProgress()` method contains, I'd guess that `showProgress` runs, sees that there is no active `login` attempt happening, and dismisses itself, then the `login()` method is called.

What you want to do is start `login()` asynchronously and then start the progress dialog that will check to see if `login()` is finished.

This is just a guess from what I can see of your code.

Could you post some more of it perhaps?

Try putting some **logcat** logging into the `showProgress()` method to see if it is in fact being created and destroyed quickly.

Comment: No, `showProgress()` did not destroy quickly, `login()` also works properly, If i click back button in home activity i can get `main activity` and its `progress dialog`

Answer (score 0):

Do your Time Consuming Task in the AsynchTask. [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class is designed exactly for the kind of work you are looking for.Use doInBackground() method to accomplish the task and onPreExecute you can show a progress Dialog.